# Exception while trying to fetch an un-grouped-by column in jdbc

Tags: jdbc

I have a table called test, defined as followed:

```
A bigint(20) NOT NULL
B bigint(20) NULL
```

I'm trying to execute the following prepared statement:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM  test GROUP BY B";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

But I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 'anya_products.test.A' isn't in GROUP BY
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2293)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
```

The exact same query works in SQLYog. What is the problem? JDBC limitation?

Thanks
Udi

Comment: group by is intended to be used with aggregation functions (sum, count, avg, etc.) What would you like to do exactly? Don't you want order by B instead?

Comment: Nope. Not that it matters, but let's say I want to use 
     HAVING count(b)=1

Comment: I suggest you edit your question with an example dataset, and what you would like the query to return.

Comment: It doesn't matter. The data is not important. There is an SQLSyntax exception..

Comment: Since the SQL is invalid, MySQL doesn't know what you want to do, and we don't know either. But if you don't want to get help...

Comment: Insert queries:

INSERT INTO test VALUES(4,1);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(5,1);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(6,2);
SELECT * FROM  test GROUP BY B HAVING count(B)=1;

Expected result: 6, 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with. Not sure it's the most efficient or the only way, but it seems to at least work:

```
select test.a, test.b from test 
inner join (select b, count(b) from test group by b having count(b) = 1) as c
    on test.b = c.b
```